# How to delete object from onclick in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I have a `RecyclerView` of objects and wants to be able to delete objects through an `onClickListener` in the list. I am thinking the easiest way would be to make the `onClickListener` recognize which index on the recyclerview is clicked and then do some objectList.remove(index), but i am not quite sure if that is possible?

Another way would be for the `OnClickListener` to recognize the name of the object i represents from at `TextView` and iterate through my ObjectList, but that doesn't seem quite as efficient as the first.

How can i make my `OnClickListener` recognise which list item it belongs to? Or is there another way i haven't been able to see?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `OnClickListener` inside the `onCreateView()` method of your `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

```
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                         .inflate(R.layout.holder_layout, parent, false);
  final CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(v);
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
     public void onClick(View view) {
      int adapterPos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
      if (adapterPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        //now you can use adapterPos to get the item in your list
      }
    }
  });
```

[This video](https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs?t=35m46s) will elaborate.

Comment: I think that does it.
Thank you!